# Closing single node server connection closes them all

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I barely ask any questions on Stack Overflow, but this one is beyond me. I guess I'm missing something basic as I'm pretty new to Node server.

Our application is pretty basic. The server is supposed to receive a handful of text lines (data), merge and parse them, and once the connection is closed (data sending is over) it sends the data to the api.

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios')

const server = new net.Server();
server.listen(PORT, IP);

server.on("connection", client => {
    client.write("Hello\n");
    console.log('connected');
    
    let received = "";
    client.on("data", data => {
       received += data
       console.log("Partial data is: " + data);
    });

    client.on("close", () => {
        received = received.toString('utf8');
        fs.appendFile('log.txt', received, function (err) {});

        received = received.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "||");
        axios.post(APIADDRESS, {data: received});
        console.log('Full data is: '+ {data: received});
    });
});
```

To send the data I'm simply running a `netcat` or `nc` using the `netcat ipaddress port`, that's not a problem. It's connecting fine, status message is received.

The thing is - once I open two or more connections from two DIFFERENT SSh servers something weird happens. I can send the line after line just fine. The server reports back "partial data" debug without problem, for both of them.
However, once I close one of the connections (ctrl+c) they BOTH close.
In the end, only the data from the manually closed connection is received. The other one, from a separate `nc` on a separate ssh server never reaches the `client.on("close")` part, it seems. It's just terminated for no reason.

Any ideas? I don't even know where to start.

//EDIT
Just tested it from my pc and some ssh mobile app using separated SSH servers. As soon as ctrl+c is sent at any device it closes the connection for all clients.

//Forgot to mention I'm running pm2 to keep the server up. Once I turned on the script by hand, ignoring pm2 - it works fine. Weird. It is happening because of PM2.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the netcat command line you're using?  And, you're doing it from two separate computers?  Or two separate consoles on the same computer?  And, you're doing the Ctrl-C from where?

Comment: I'm running putty, 2 instances of different ssh servers (two windows opened), but a single computer. I'm just doing ctrl-c in one of the consoles.

Comment: Any idea if putty is sharing connections between the instances somehow?  Perhaps read this: [Sharing connections with Putty](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-ssh-sharing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone coming here in the future.

If you are using **pm2 with --watch enabled** and the text log file is in the same folder as your main server script... That's the reason why it drops the connection after a single client disconnects. It just detects that the log has changed.

I'm not facepalming, that's not even funny.

Comment: So, pm2 is restarting your server when the SSH log file is modified?  Are you saying this is the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have Putty configured to  ‘Share SSH connections if possible’.  Per some doc, when doing so:

> When this mode is in use, the first PuTTY that connected to a given server becomes the ‘upstream’, which means that it is the one managing the real SSH connection. All subsequent PuTTYs which reuse the connection are referred to as ‘downstreams’: they do not connect to the real server at all, but instead connect to the upstream PuTTY via local inter-process communication methods.

So, if you Ctrl+C the PuTTY session that is managing the actual shared connection, they both lose their connection.

You could presumably disable this shared connection feature at either the client or server end of things since both must be enabled for sharing to occur.

Comment: I disabled it and set it to upstream, however, as I said these are two completely separatable ssh servers I'm using for `netcat`. That's what bothers me the most. I guess I'd need to test it on two devices at once, just to be sure.

Comment: Nope, just tested it from my pc and some ssh mobile app. As soon as ctrl+c is sent at any device it closes the connection for all clients.